# Posting an action with user generated photo on ios share dialog

Tags: ios, share, facebook-opengraph, user-input, photo

What i was trying to do was to publish a camera generated photo into facebook with an open graph action.

here is the code i used:

```
UIImage *imageToShare = [EXPOINNOVAImageCombiner mergeImages:photo TopImage:tbot];
    //Custom UIImage to be shared on facebook

    NSArray* images = @[@{@"url": imageToShare, @"user_generated" : @"true" }];

    id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
    [action setObject:@"http://emaginelab.com/FBAction/fbtbot.html" forKey:@"tbot"];
    [action setObject:images forKey:@"image"];

    [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:action
                                          actionType:@"expoinnovaapp:took_a_photo_with"
                                 previewPropertyName:@"tbot"
                                             handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                                 if(error) {
                                                     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                                 } else {
                                                     NSLog(@"Success!");
                                                 }
                                             }];
```

When i set the user_generated flag to false, the post works, but if its true facebook tries to post it, but falls back to the app before the upload finishes.

I already registered my app in facebook, and added the user generated photos capability so, in theory, the app should post a larger version of the photo in the user timeline.

btw the image is 640x640

what am i doing wrong here?

thanks in advance

Comment: EricDS, according to the (recently updated) docs, images must be within the 480x480 size limit. If you are getting an error code of 102, that may be your issue. Not sure if you resolved this or not, but I am having similar issues posting using the Share Dialog (although my image size is 'seemingly' correct).

Comment: turns out the method i was using created an image 2x size when used from an iphone 4 or later, because of the retina display. At the end i just had to scale the image according to the device's pixel density.